# user's Internet Access logs in Network

Tags: ubuntu, freeradius

I  working on freeradius management system .
user can access internet after  insert his username and password .
after user can access internet he will surf internet .
every things go fine but my problem is ,
I want to register all users  access websites while  he used my wifi  .I searched for days  about this without result . freeradius can not register users activities .
is there any way to access my goal.

Comment: there are no answers about my question !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Please help me

Comment: Hey - you do understand that this is a community, not paid consultants for you, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have something that actually knows about the traffic. As you say, RADIUS doesn't do that; it's authentication and authorization to *use* (or be on) a network. There's a few approaches to solve this problem.

1. Put a software agent on the end-user's machine that records all web traffic.
2. Force all internet-bound traffic through a proxy server that logs.
3. Do some form of packet capture or traffic logging at the internet gateway.

All of these will have pros and cons for your specific use case; they may need extra work to capture encrypted traffic.

That's to say nothing of whether or not this is allowed in your company or country.

Comment: thank you for your reply but I can not install software on the end user's machine because my system will working on general places like park , hotels ...etc

Comment: That's why I listed the most common ways to accomplish the goal. Items 2 and 3 don't involve putting software on the client machine.

Comment: are there any program working on ubuntu that can help me to register all visited sites ?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.htm : if you have constraints in your environment, it's a good idea to post them as part of the question.

Comment: how can I Force all internet-bound traffic through a proxy server that logs.

Comment: Regarding what programs you can use - this site is not for product suggestions; please read the Help Center.

Comment: I am so sorry about my many questions

Comment: Regarding how to force traffic through a proxy : you could use proxy discovery, or use a transparent proxy as your gateway. Obviously, this community is here to help other people and answer questions, but you have *got* to start with doing some of your own research.